# Mac VoiceOver reads list items twice

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, voiceover

Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>World</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using VoiceOver on Mac OS X 10.11.5. When I navigate this page with `VO+A`, I hear the following:

> HTML Content
>
> List two items
>
> Bullet Hello, group
>
> Hello
>
> Bullet World, group
>
> World
>
> You are currently on a text element.

However, if I navigate with `VO+left arrow` and `VO+right arrow`, I get:

> List two items
>
> Bullet Hello
>
> Bullet World
>
> End of list

Why is there a discrepancy between the two traversal options? And how can I avoid having `VO+A` read the content twice? (`Bullet Hello, group / Hello`.) That seems sub-optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can replicate this behavior. Given the simplicity of the case, I can't imagine a workaround. I'd suggest filing a [Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com). At best, engineers may reply with a workaround. At worst, it's expected behavior that's consistent with users' experiences across all websites.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that suggestion. Does the Radar link work for you? When I enter my correct username and password, it just redirects to the same login page and asks for my creds again. When I use incorrect creds, I get an error message.

Comment: Bug report #27954009 filed. Somehow the login page started working. Thanks for this suggestion.