# VoiceOver on Mac reads headings h1, h2, etc., twice. Is the HTML wrong?

Tags: macos, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

VoiceOver is reading headings twice, but in HTML they are listed only once. There are no ID's or references.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample text with image</title>
</head> 

<body>
    <h1>How to prepare a veggie curry</h1>
```

VO will read "How to prepare a veggie curry" twice. Why is that? Is that preferred?

Comment: Do you have any scripting happening on this page? Also, are you closing out your body and html elements? It wasn't included in your code sample, so I thought I would ask.

Comment: The above example works as intended, can you provide a fiddle or similar that has the behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028031/mac-voiceover-reads-list-items-twice?rq=1

Comment: A good example showing how to link headers with their sections (html5): https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/example/. Looks like you need to relate your title tags to the sections they link to.